# For a Krasovskii Regularized System, does there exist a Cartheodory Solution for all $t_{0},x_{0}\in [0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{d}$ w/ IC x(t_0)=x_0

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, control-theory

The differential inclusion associated with a time-varying set valued map $F:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{d}\to\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is an equation of the following form
$$\dot{x}(t)\in F(t,x(t)).$$

Here $\mathfrak{B}(S)$ is the set whose elements are all of the possible subsets of $S\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Following proposition S2 of *Discontinuous Dynamical Systems: A Tutorial on Solutions, Nonsmooth Analysis, and Stability* by Jorge Cortes:

Let $F:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{d}\to\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be locally bounded and take non-empty, compact, and convex values. Assume that, for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the set-value map $x\mapsto F(t,x)$ is upper semicontinuous, and, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, the set-valued map $t\mapsto F(t,x)$ is measurable. Then for all $(t_{0},x_{0})\in[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{d}$, there exists a Caratheodory solution with initial condition (IC) $x(t_{0})=x_0$.

Next, the Krasovskii regularization for $F$ is defined as
$$\hat{F}(x)\triangleq\bigcap_{\delta >0}\overline{\text{co}}F(x+\delta\mathbb{B}).$$

Note, I am taking this definition from *Hybrid Dynamical Systems: Modeling, Stability, and Robustness* by Goebel, Sanfelice, and Teel.

To me it seems that Krasovskii regularization satisfies all the requirements for the existence of Caratheodory solutions, but I am uncertain about the measurability condition. I am not even sure what it means for a set-valued mapping to be measurable.

Additional Information:

Example 6.6 and Lemma 5.16 of the Goebel text gets me the following:

1. $\hat{F}$ is outer semicontinuous
2. $\hat{F}$ is locally bounded relative to a flow set $C$
3. $\hat{F}$ is convex valued for every $x\in C$

For a flow map $F$ that evolves over a flow set $C$, the Krasovskii regularization is
$$\hat{F}(x)\triangleq\bigcap_{\delta >0}\overline{\text{co}}F((x+\delta\mathbb{B})\cap C),\quad\forall x\in C.$$

If additional information is needed, let me know, I'll do my best to fix the problem.

Upper semicontinuity information:

Image of text: [Set Valued maps information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbttP.png)
Link to text: https://bonetto.math.gatech.edu/teaching/6307-fall20/DiscDynSys.pdf

See page 74 and 75

In Aubin's Set-Valued Analysis text I found the following on measurability:
[Measurable Set-Valued Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd4yq.png)

From the same text: If $F$ is upper semi-continuous (or lower), then $F$ is measurable.
[Continuity implies measurability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z0Sy.png)

Comment: How are  lower semicontinuity and measurability in the context of relations (as opposed to functions) defined in your textbook? In economic problems and control problems I have heard of lower (upper) hemicontinuity and weak measurability, weak measurability and measurability. All this in terms of sets of the form $F^\ell(A):=\{x: F(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset\}$ and $F^u(A)=\{x: F(x)\subset A\}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz See, that is one of the problems I am running into. In the Cortes' IEEE Control Systems Magazine, measurability of a set-valued isn't explicitly defined, and the citations aren't shedding any light on this issue for me. As for upper semicontinuity, I am placing an image from the text in the body of the post.

Comment: Here is a couple of references that may help you: Deimling, K., *Nonlinear Analysis*, Dover, Chapter 8 (Klaus calls correspondence or set valued functions multis); Aliprantis, C., and Border, K., *Infinite dimensional analysis: A Hitchkiker's Guide, Springer, 3rd edition, chapters 17-18. The former may be closer top what you need, the later has useful material.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Great, thanks! I am going to head over to the library now.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I found and added some information of measurability of set-valued maps. Additionally, Prop 8.2.1 of Aubin's text says that if $F$ is upper semicontinuous (or lower), then $F$ is measurable. Given this it seems that I should now be able to satisfy all the necessary conditions for Carathedory solutions.

Comment: Glad to know you found some other good sources. It seems that you have your question answer through your one search. I have not worked on those types of problems in ages, I now remember looking at  Aubin's book. Alliprantie's book have also many references on the subject. He was an expert on economic problems that require the theory of multis (or correspondences).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but I just want to comment to clarify one point (since I'm looking at similar things). I think the problem of measurability is crucial for local existence of solutions only when the differential equation (or inclusion) is time-varying (a.k.a non-autonomous).

Indeed, in the existence theorems, it is asked that the map $F:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable with respect to the first variable (time), for any \emph{fixed} $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. for any fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the function $t\mapsto F(t,x)$ is measurable. Then, it is always required a (stronger) continuity property in the second variable (the state): for any fixed $t\in \mathbb{R}$ the function $x\mapsto F(t,x)$ has to be continuous (for ODE, Charatheodory existence theorem) or upper semicontinuous with non-empty,convex compact values (for differential inclusion, Filippov Theorem and affine versions). For uniqueness and forward completeness (the maximal solutions are defined on $[0,+\infty]$), other hypothesis are generally needed.

When the differential inclusion/equation is not time-dependent, i.e. it is autonomuous, checking the continuity/upper semicontinity(and the rest) is enough for existence of solution in the Charatheodory sense. But of course continuity and upper semicontinuity imply (with compact convex non-empty values) measurability, as you pointed out.